# return a default record from a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query that I run against a sql server database eg.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id = 2
```

This may return a number of records or may return none. If it returns none, I would like to alter my sql query to return a default record, is this possible and if so, how? If records are returned, the default record should not be returned. I cannot update the data so will need to alter the sql query for this.

Comment: what kind of data should contain the default record?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679865/return-a-value-if-no-rows-are-found-sql

Comment: @MaxNanasy: thats not a duplicate because that is about returning a default value if no matching rows were found. This is about returning a default record(not only a single value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way (you would get an empty initial rowset returned);

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id = 2
IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
   SELECT ...
```

Comment: But this will return two resultsets. I guess OP (and most others coming here) are looking for a solution which gives them always at least one record for the original query with default values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
SELECT ID,1 as Flag FROM MyTable WHERE Id = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2
) qry
ORDER BY qry.Flag ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to this post. It is similar to what you are asking 
[Return a value if no rows are found SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679865/return-a-value-if-no-rows-are-found-sql)

I hope that it can guide you to the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

if not exists (`SELECT top 1 * FROM mytable WHERE id = 2`)

```
select * from mytable where id=  'whatever_the_default_id_is'
```

else

```
select * from mytable where id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to return whole rows of data (and not just a single column) and you have to create a single SQL query then do this:

### Left join actual table to defaults single-row table

```
select
    coalesce(a.col1, d.col1) as col1,
    coalesce(a.col2, d.col2) as col2,
    ...
from (
    -- your defaults record
    select
        default1 as col1,
        default2 as col2,
        ...) as d
    left join actual as a
    on ((1 = 1) /* or any actual table "where" conditions */)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query need to return the same number of fields, so you shouldn't do a `SELECT * FROM` but a `SELECT value FROM` if you want to return a default value.

With that in mind

```
SELECT value FROM MyTable WHERE Id = 2
UNION
SELECT CASE (SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Id = 2) 
   WHEN 0 THEN 'defaultvalue' 
   END
```