# SQL select return 0 if no records found, else return value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am now using Microsoft SQL, my code is:

```
   SELECT TOP 1 
   [avail]
   FROM [table1]
   where [name] = 'abc'
   order by [datetime] desc
```

I hope when [avail] exists, return the value of [avail], if not exists, return 0 or "Not Found"

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just deal with that in your presentation layer? Thats the right place for this sort of logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a value if no rows are found SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679865/return-a-value-if-no-rows-are-found-sql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this

```
SELECT ISNULL(( SELECT TOP 1 
   [avail]
   FROM [table1]
   where [name] = 'abc'
   order by [datetime] desc), 0) AS [avail]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two ways:

Use `IF EXISTS` way:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 [avail] FROM [table1] WHERE [name] = 'abc' ORDER BY [datetime] DESC)
    SELECT TOP 1 [avail] FROM [table1] WHERE [name] = 'abc' ORDER BY [datetime] DESC
ELSE 
    SELECT 0 AS [avail]
```

or store the `avail` value into a variable and process, the only risk in this way is if the `top 1 avail` is returns empty value, then you will get the result as zero.

```
DECLARE @Avail AS VARCHAR(100) = ''; -- varchar of the `avail` data size

SELECT TOP 1 @Avail = [avail] FROM [table1] WHERE [name] = 'abc' ORDER BY [datetime] DESC;

IF @Avail = ''
    SELECT 0 AS [avail]
ELSE 
    SELECT @Avail AS [avail]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use COALESCE. It selects the data from the first argument that has a nonnull value. If avail is not null, return [avale], otherwise return "Not Found"

```
SELECT COALESCE(avail, 'Not Found')
FROM table1
WHERE name = 'abc'
ORDER BY datetime desc
```

You can read about COALESCE in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use sum() function, like this

```
select nvl(sum(columnA), 0) from your_table where your_condition;
```

It will return 0 if no rows are there

Answer (score -1):

If its top 1 you want or remove top command

```
 SELECT TOP 1 
   isnull([avail],'0')
   FROM [table1]
   where [name] = 'abc'
   order by [datetime] desc
```