# displaying a value even if no rows returned

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a situation in oracle SQL.

```
select x from A where x=10;
```

so if `10` exists in the column, value will be displayed `10`. but if it doesn't exists I want to display `null`. I tried `NVL` but it is not returning anything as data is not displaying.

Could you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a value if no rows are found SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679865/return-a-value-if-no-rows-are-found-sql)

Comment: When there are more rows than one that match, do you want all that rows in the result or only ever one row?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return multiple rows from the original `SELECT` then you can use `UNION ALL` to add a row when the value does not exist:

```sql
SELECT x
FROM   A
WHERE  x = 10
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT x
  FROM   A
  WHERE  x = 10
)
```

If your table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a ( x ) AS
SELECT 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the query will output:

> ```
> |  X |
> | -: |
> | 10 |
> | 10 |
> | 10 |
> ```

Then if you `DELETE FROM a;` and repeat the query, it will output:

> ```
> |    X |
> | ---: |
> | null |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e7d9429506b034b7de16ac873b9d958d)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select max(x) 
from A
where x = 10; --this will return null if no data
```

And then you can do a NVL:

```
select nvl(max(x), 0) 
from A
where x = 10; --this will return 0 if no data
```

Answer (score 0):

`Where` clause filter out the data what you are looking for, if it doesn't exists then query will return no record.

So, you can remove `where` clause & do aggregation :

```
select max(case when a.x = 10 then 10 end)
from a;
```